# Picture storing library on jquery or symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony

I am making the application which has the function like this.

User can upload or delete the multiple image file.
You can use this like facebook album.

I made this function from the scratch,Howevere, it's not so good..

Now I search the jquery library for this purpose,
but mainly I can find only the visual focused library for super cool design site.

However my application is mainly for administration purpose.
Picture sorting and stocking are enough, cool slideshow and dissolve are not necessary.

Is there any recommendation or good suggestion for this purpose ?

I am using symfony2 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:
[Sonata media bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/index.html)

It's a symfony2 bundle designed for administrating media(images/videos/other_things_you_can_think_of) within an administration panel.
You can store your media based on albums, groups or standalone.
You can also store external sources like dailymotion, youtube, etc.

It might be exactly what you're looking for, and it comes with almost no configuration needed. The docs are pretty self-explanatory also.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question because Sonata media bundle cannot be used stand alone due to it's many dependencies with other bundles of the Sonata project (and not only).

Comment: I am using sonatadminbundle already, so I will try it . What I worry is I dont want user have admin account , I have three user group administrator(me), teacher user, student user. Currently ,Administrator can access the sonataadminbundle and teacher user access the management panel I made. So I will integrate sonatamediabundle in management panel apart from sonataadminbundle. I am not sure is it possible, anyway I will try thanks very much.

Comment: It is possible to use the sonata media functionality outside of the sonata admin. You simply use the media providers of sonata, and even the sonata media templates(the pretty popup).

Comment: I wrote my previous comment because Sonata was not mentioned/tagged in the question. @pcm I never used Sonata but [reading the official documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html) it doesn't seems to be possible to use the bundle outside it's dependencies (maybe for use all the functionalities?).

Comment: I am trying sonata media bundle. I am still struggling with bundle though,I will report how I solve the problem.

Comment: Great news. If you need help just ask